# Tooltip to show a keystroke in java

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

Pressing the Control key I want to show a Jtooltip of a Jbutton.

How can I show a tooltip to the desired keystrokes?

Comment: put some code or research efforts plz

Comment: Do you want it done for a particular button or the currently focused button?

Comment: [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) will help

Comment: Keystrokes are understood, without raising the mouse on the object, Is there a way to show the tooltip? @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand the question, but you can use `Control+F1` to display the tooltip of the currently focused component.

Comment: Without the movement of the mouse, you can show a tooltip with the specified key input? @MadProgrammer

Comment: @Sibal Try it and see.  Once the control has focus, ctrl+F1 will show the tooltip

Answer (score 1):

There is a `private` method in the `TooltipManager` called `show` which takes a `JComponent` as a parameter, which is used to show the tooltip.  This is actually used by the `TooltipManager` when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is pressed...

So, my first recommendation would be, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> because it's built in.  My second recommendation is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> because people press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for a lot of reasons (like copy/paste, menu short cuts, etc), which could be rather annoying if you keep popping up tool tips all the time.  My third recommendation is to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> because the `show` method is `private`

However, because I'm simply curious (and completely crazy), you "could" (but I wouldn't recommend it) use a dirty, dirty hack (I fell like Phillip Fry), which is just as likely to blow up in your face as solve the problem (but I was curious about how to bind an action to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key)

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import static javax.swing.JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JButton btn = new JButton("Banana");
            btn.setToolTipText("Hello");
            add(btn);
            TooltipPopup.register(this);
        }

    }

    public static class TooltipPopup {

        public static void register(JComponent comp) {
            new TooltipPopup(comp);
        }

        private JComponent parent;
        private boolean showing = false;

        private TooltipPopup(JComponent parent) {
            this.parent = parent;
            bindKeyStrokeTo(parent,
                            JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT,
                            "help.press",
                            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK),
                            new AbstractAction() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    if (!showing) {
                                        Component comp = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
                                        if (comp != null && comp instanceof JComponent) {
                                            JComponent focused = (JComponent) comp;
                                            try {
                                                Class clazz = ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().getClass();
                                                Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("show", JComponent.class);
                                                method.setAccessible(true);
                                                method.invoke(ToolTipManager.sharedInstance(), focused);
                                                showing = true;
                                            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                                                ex.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
            bindKeyStrokeTo(parent,
                            JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT,
                            "help.release",
                            KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, 0, true),
                            new AbstractAction() {
                                @Override
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                    showing = false;
                                }
                            });
        }

        public void bindKeyStrokeTo(JComponent parent, int condition, String name, KeyStroke keyStroke, Action action) {
            InputMap im = parent.getInputMap(condition);
            ActionMap am = parent.getActionMap();

            im.put(keyStroke, name);
            am.put(name, action);
        }

    }

}
```

All this does is binds a press and release `Action` to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> for a given component (parent container), which will find the currently focused component and show it's tool tip.

It uses a reflection "tick" (hack) to call the `private` `show` method of the `ToolTipManager`.

You need the "press" and "release" actions, because otherwise you will get a repeated key event, which will make the tool tip "flash"

**camickr solution is the better (and correct) choice, this was a simply "I wonder how" hack**

Comment: Thanks to your efforts. There are programming using the Flamingo, CTRL F1 is not working, I was looking the other way.Perhaps, if CTRL is often a problem, it is the better if we do use the ALT?

Comment: It's more of the key combination, ctrl or alt alone is not a good idea as they tend to be used to generate other key strokes.  Maybe you should bind ctrl+F1 yourself